# How do I handle Microsoft outlook winmail.dat? Any other surprises?

Tags: java, python, email, jython, winmail.dat

Ive decided that I really dont like microsoft and their ways. Please could you give me directions on how to handle winmail.dat in emails, is there a jython library or a java library that will allow me to handle this.

Ive just completed a email processing program, written in jython 2.2.1 on java 5. During the final load test, I realised that attachments that should have been in a standard MIME email format is now tied up in some blasted winmail.dat, which means many different outlook clients pollute the internet with this winmail.dat, so that means i need to support winmail.dat. Thus my program failed to process the data correctly.

Please could you give a short description on what winmail.dat is and why it is here to annoy us.

What other surprises can be expected!? what else do I have to watch out for, so far standard MIME emails are catered for. Are there any other jack in the boxes?

Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: 10 years later and this is still haunting me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

read here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TNEF

a package for parsing here:
https://github.com/verdammelt/tnef

Comment: just as i posted you guys posted

Answer (score 6):

Topic closed, but for future purposes: [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) project (Java API for Microsoft Documents) is launching a version (3.8) that is capable to decode TNEF files. I tested it and worked very well, even the beta version. You can found it [here](http://poi.apache.org/hmef/index.html).

To use with maven (june 2016 - might change later when it is no longer in the scratchpad):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
        <version>3.14</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: It worked nicely for me too; the website is a bit misleading, claiming that one has to build it locally. I've submitted a bug report https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59679

Answer (score 3):

> Please could you give a short
>   description on what winmail.dat is and
>   why it is here to annoy us.

[kb138053](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/138053)

> When an end user sends mail to the
>   Internet from an Exchange Windows or
>   Outlook client, a file attachment
>   called Winmail.dat may be
>   automatically added to the end of the
>   message if the recipient's client
>   cannot receive messages in Rich Text
>   Format (RTF). The Winmail.dat file
>   contains Exchange Server RTF
>   information for the message, and may
>   appear to the recipient as a binary
>   file. It is not useful to non-Exchange
>   Server recipients.

If you read the kb I referenced further it gives instructions on how Exchange administrators can and **should** disable RTF to the internet.

Answer (score 1):

so when i see this in email Content-Type:
"application/ms-tnef"

I use this:
http://www.freeutils.net/source/jtnef/

Answer (score 1):

Just a comment about tinnef: Not everything that is called winmail.dat is ordinary TNEF. Meeting inviations sent from Outlook are not, thus most TNEF decoders will fail in this case.
On Mac OSX, I found "Letter Opener" to be one of the rare programs that can open such attachments. Funny enough, they can also contain rtf documents.

http://www.restoroot.org/LetterOpenerPro

Answer (score 1):

There's also a pure-Python [tnefparse](https://pypi.org/project/tnefparse/) package. It should be possible to use that from Jython.

Answer (score 0):

I have had good luck with [wmdecode](http://www.biblet.freeserve.co.uk/) on Windows. Granted, it's an EXE, not a java project. But it could be useful if you run into WINMAIL.DAT files that other solutions can't decode.