# Handling winmail.dat using java mail api

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, email-attachments, winmail.dat

I am using JavaMail API to get attachments and some of them are in form of **winmail.dat**.

As stated in [get email attatchment for POP 3 received as winmail.dat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14949671/get-email-attatchment-for-pop-3-received-as-winmail-dat) or [How do I handle Microsoft outlook winmail.dat? Any other surprises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336517/how-do-i-handle-microsoft-outlook-winmail-dat-any-other-surprises)

I tried both https://github.com/jukka/jtnef/blob/master/src/net/freeutils/tnef/TNEF.java
and also apache : https://poi.apache.org/hmef/

and when I parse the winmail.dat file, I only get the *`MAPIProperties`*, but no attachment files, when I debug the constructed Message instance, the attachment array is empty and we have only some attributes and `MAPIProperties` and 0 attachments.

But when we fetch using other tools for example **Zimbra**, we get the real `VCALENDAR` file as an attachment.

> BEGIN:VCALENDAR
>
> METHOD:REQUEST
>
> CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
>
> BEGIN:VTIMEZONE

***Question:*** How can we extract the `VCALENDAR` file from `winmail.dat` or is there any way to convert the `MAPIProperites` to `VCALENDAR`?

**For example** we have in the output of jtnef:

> MAPIProp: type=PT_UNICODE_STRING name=[GUID=00.. id=0x..
>   value=MyAttendee

but in the real (correct) `VCalendar` file:

**`ATTENDEE;CN=MyAttendee`**

Comment: Also tried the http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/scratchpad/src/org/apache/poi/hmef/dev/HMEFDumper.java, it returns 0 attachments, lots of properties in level 1.